# [PHP]Сайт пока не может обработать этот запрос

Tags: php

Создал форму, при попытке отправить сайт выдает ошибку "Сайт пока не может обработать этот запрос." 
Ниже код скрипта отправки. В чем проблема?

```
 <?php
// Переменные
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $car = $_POST['car'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $mailto = '12345@yandex.ru;'
//Отправка
    mail($mailto ,$name ,$contact , $car , $model, $year );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сайт пока не может обработать этот запрос - это 500 ошибка на сервере. Строка ниже вызывает ошибку критическую интерпретатора, из-за которой скрипт не может быть обработан.

```
$mailto = '12345@yandex.ru;' //должно быть $mailto = '12345@yandex.ru';
```

Вы передаете слишком много параметров в mail и возможно неправильные, функция принимает следующие аргументы:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string
>   $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

[Описание работы функции на официальном сайте php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)